# REGEX performance in SQL

Tags: mysql, regex, database

I want to select all cities that start and ends with vowel character. I see different ways but I am confused which is better performance?

```
select distinct city from the station 

SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM station
WHERE left(city, 1) IN (
        'a'
        ,'e'
        ,'i'
        ,'o'
        ,'u'
        )
    AND right(city, 1) IN (
        'a'
        ,'e'
        ,'i'
        ,'o'
        ,'u'
        )
```

the second-way using regex :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM station
WHERE city regexp '[aeiou]$'
    AND city IN (
        SELECT CITY
        FROM STATION
        WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[aeiou]'
        );
```

and the last way is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE (
        lower(city) LIKE 'a%'
        OR lower(city) LIKE 'e%'
        OR lower(city) LIKE 'i%'
        OR lower(city) LIKE 'o%'
        OR lower(city) LIKE 'u%'
        )
    AND (
        lower(city) LIKE '%a'
        OR lower(city) LIKE '%e'
        OR lower(city) LIKE '%i'
        OR lower(city) LIKE '%o'
        OR lower(city) LIKE '%u'
        )
```

Which is better and why?

Comment: Tag correctly. MySQL is not TSQL and they use different sql dialects. TSQL has no regex function.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend regular expressions, but like this:

```
select distinct city
from station 
where city regexp '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$';
```

That is, a single regular expression.

As for what is best . . . that depends on your definition of "best".  Simpler string operations (`left()` and `right()`) might have slightly better performance than regular expressions (you should check; this is not always true).

I prefer this because it is concise and exactly matches the question you are asking.

Comment: please can you explain the regex that you type 
and If you could recommend some resources to master REGEX in SQL 
Thanks

Comment: @heshamahmed . . . Regular expressions in SQL are just like regular expressions anywhere else (or close enough).  There are numerous tutorials and explanations on the web to help you learn them.

Comment: For performance, this query may be the fastest -- Most solutions need to fetch all rows; fetching the rows is the bulk of the effort.  Regexp vs LEFT vs etc is minor.